# How to get a contextmenu to appear on right click of a datagridview cell

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a form with a datagrid on it. What I want to be able to do is have a drop down menu appear next to the mouse when I right click a cell. I need to be able to select an option from the menu and run some stuff.

I can get the right click event to register, but the contextmenu won't appear.
The menu in the code below should appear with the option to copy the cell.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Drawing”)
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1040,518)
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.StartPosition = 'centerscreen'
$form.BackColor = 'MidnightBlue'
$form.Add_KeyDown({if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){$form.Close()}})
$form.Text = "VIOC Toolkit 5.4" 
$form.Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell_ise.exe")
$form.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1040,525)

$DataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGrid1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(298,29)
$DataGrid1.Dock = "Fill"
$DataGrid1.BorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'    
$DataGrid1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font($dgfont,$dgfontSize)
$DataGrid1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 'LightGray'
$DataGrid1.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$DataGrid1.RowHeadersVisible = $false
$DataGrid1.BackgroundColor = "White"
$DataGrid1.Name="DataGrid1"
$DataGrid1.Text="DataGrid1"
$DataGrid1.ColumnCount = 3
$DataGrid1.Columns[0].Name = 'one'
$DataGrid1.Columns[1].Name = 'two'
$DataGrid1.Columns[2].Name = 'three'
$DataGrid1.Rows.add(@('a', 'b', 'c'))
$DataGrid1.Rows.add(@('d', 'e', 'f'))
#*************************************************************#    
$DataGrid1.add_CellMouseClick({
    if($_.button -eq 'Right'){
        ContextMenu($DataGrid1)
    }
})

function ContextMenu($Grid){
    #create the context menu
    $menu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
    $CopyMenuItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $copymenuItem.text = 'copy'
    $copymenuItem.add_Click({write-host 'clicked copy'})
    $menu.MenuItems.AddRange(@($CopyMenuItem))

}

#***************************************************************#
$form.Controls.Add($DataGrid1)
$form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `DataGridViews` own `ContextMenuStrip` instead of creating a new context menu.

Comment: Well in the long run I'm not going to have Copy on the menu, but that was an easy example to ask about. The menu is going to me custom.

Comment: A context menu is a context menu.... what is "Custom" about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Drawing”)
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1040,518)
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.StartPosition = 'centerscreen'
$form.BackColor = 'MidnightBlue'
$form.Add_KeyDown({if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){$form.Close()}})
$form.Text = "VIOC Toolkit 5.4" 
$form.Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell_ise.exe")
$form.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1040,525)

[System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView] $DataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGrid1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(298,29)
$DataGrid1.Dock = "Fill"
$DataGrid1.BorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'    
#$DataGrid1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font $dgfont,$dgfontSize
$DataGrid1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 'LightGray'
$DataGrid1.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$DataGrid1.RowHeadersVisible = $false
$DataGrid1.BackgroundColor = "White"
$DataGrid1.Name="DataGrid1"
$DataGrid1.Text="DataGrid1"
$DataGrid1.ColumnCount = 3
$DataGrid1.Columns[0].Name = 'one'
$DataGrid1.Columns[1].Name = 'two'
$DataGrid1.Columns[2].Name = 'three'
$DataGrid1.Rows.add(@('a', 'b', 'c'))
$DataGrid1.Rows.add(@('d', 'e', 'f'))

#Creation of content click event
$ClickElementMenu=
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem]$sender = $args[0]
    [System.EventArgs]$e= $args[1]

    $Contentcell=$DataGrid1.Rows[$DataGrid1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[$DataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value
    $ElementMenuClicked=$sender.Text
    $RowIndex=$DataGrid1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    $ColIndex=$DataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex


    $result="Click on element menu : '{0}' , in rowindex : {1} , column : {2}, content cell : {3}" -f $ElementMenuClicked,  $RowIndex, $ColIndex, $Contentcell;
    Write-Host $result
}

#creation menu
$contextMenuStrip1=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip

#creation element1 of menu
[System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem]$toolStripItem1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
$toolStripItem1.Text = "Element 1";
$toolStripItem1.add_Click($ClickElementMenu)
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add($toolStripItem1);

#creation element2 of menu
[System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem]$toolStripItem2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
$toolStripItem2.Text = "Element 2";
$toolStripItem2.add_Click($ClickElementMenu)
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add($toolStripItem2);

#creation event of mouse down on datagrid and show menu when click
$DataGrid1.add_MouseDown({
    $sender = $args[0]
    [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]$e= $args[1]

    if ($e.Button -eq  [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right)
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView+HitTestInfo] $hit = $DataGrid1.HitTest($e.X, $e.Y);
        if ($hit.Type -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHitTestType]::Cell)
        {
            $DataGrid1.CurrentCell = $DataGrid1[$hit.ColumnIndex, $hit.RowIndex];
            $contextMenuStrip1.Show($DataGrid1, $e.X, $e.Y);
        }

    }
})




#***************************************************************#
$form.Controls.Add($DataGrid1)
$form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code presents a good example of the type of behavior I was looking to get and gave me some ideas about how to convert all the c# examples I've been seeing into PowerShell.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a minimal C# example

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewContextMenu_45574948
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingList<dgvitem> dgvitems = new BindingList<dgvitem>();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeTheGrid();
        }

        private void InitializeTheGrid()
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgv.DataSource = dgvitems;
            dgv.CellMouseClick += Dgv_CellMouseClick;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
        }

        private void Dgv_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
                mi.Text = "Menu option 1";
                mi.Click += MenuItem1Click;
                cm.MenuItems.Add(mi);
                mi = new MenuItem();
                mi.Text = "Menu option 2";
                mi.Click += MenuItem2Click;
                cm.MenuItems.Add(mi);
                cm.Show(dgv, new Point(e.Location.X + 10, e.Location.Y + 10));
            }
        }

        private void MenuItem2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something here
        }

        private void MenuItem1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something here
        }
    }

    public class dgvitem
    {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to down-vote, at least back it up with a helpful comment.

Comment: Your answer is in C# and not PowerShell; that's probably why it got downvoted.